# Module with two tables odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm new in odoo9, any example how create simple module with two tables.
First table etc. Team (teamId,teamName,teamDescription) and second table Player(playerId,teamId,playerName,playerSurname).

After add team on list below I need add player for that team

example `https://postimg.org/image/uam0v0cct/`

```
class team_module(model.Models):
    _name = 'team.module'
    _description = 'team description'

    name = fields.char('Team Name', size=128, required=True)
    description = fields.char('Team desc', size=256)


class player_module(model.Models):
    _name = 'player.module'
    _description = 'player description'

    name = fields.char('Player Name', size=128, required=True)
    surname = fields.char('Player Surname', size=128, required=True)
```

Any simple solution or module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `One2many` field in `team_module`:

```
player_ids = fields.One2many('player.module', 'player_id', string='Players')
```

Then add `player_id` to `player_module`:

```
player_id = fields.Many2one('team.module', string='Team Reference',
    ondelete='cascade', index=True)
```